# Alter the ColumnFamily compression in Hbase Table

Tags: hbase

I need to change the compression of a table from Snappy to LZO. I tried the following but doesn't work.

1. create table with SNAPPY compression.
2. disable and then alter table with LZO compression
3. Enabled and did major compact on the table

I found the `.regioninfo` files still have `COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'`.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you changed the compression codec of table. Maybe you can change by using the hbase api.

```
HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
HColumnDescriptor hcd = new HColumnDescriptor(family);
hcd.setCompressionType(Algorithm.SNAPPY);
```

In my tests snappy performs better than lzo by the way

Answer (score 0):

In the hbase shell, you can use `describe 'tableName'` to check the metadata of the table including compression, in my test environments it worked.